# Convert values - issue

Tags: javascript

I'm using [this code](https://gist.github.com/ryansmith94/91d7fd30710264affeb9) for simple `conversion` of values between different bases (baseConversion). **But there are occurring some issues that I'd love to fix!**

---

`"1234"` from *base 10 to base 3* will get `"1200201"` and decoded again to base 10 will get `"1234"` again. **So far so good.**

Encoding `"0001"` *to base 3* will get `"1"` and decoding again will get `"1"` instead of `"0001"` again.  **How to fix this?**

---

```js
function convertBase(value, from_base, to_base) {
  var range = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ+/'.split('');
  var from_range = range.slice(0, from_base);
  var to_range = range.slice(0, to_base);

  var dec_value = value.split('').reverse().reduce(function(carry, digit, index) {
    if (from_range.indexOf(digit) === -1) throw new Error('Invalid digit `' + digit + '` for base ' + from_base + '.');
    return carry += from_range.indexOf(digit) * (Math.pow(from_base, index));
  }, 0);

  var new_value = '';
  while (dec_value > 0) {
    new_value = to_range[dec_value % to_base] + new_value;
    dec_value = (dec_value - (dec_value % to_base)) / to_base;
  }
  return new_value || '0';
}

let raw = "1234"
document.body.innerHTML += "raw: " + raw + "<br>"
let encoded = convertBase(raw, 10, 3)
document.body.innerHTML += "encoded: " + encoded + "<br>"
let decoded = convertBase(encoded, 3, 10)
document.body.innerHTML += "decoded: " + decoded + "<br><br>"


raw = "0001"
document.body.innerHTML += "raw: " + raw + "<br>"
encoded = convertBase(raw, 10, 3)
document.body.innerHTML += "encoded: " + encoded + "<br>"
decoded = convertBase(encoded, 3, 10)
document.body.innerHTML += "decoded: " + decoded + "<br><br>"
```

```css
* {
  font-family: Arial;
}

i {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: gray;
}
```

```html
<b>Note</b>: "1234" from base 10 to base 3 will get <i>"1200201"</i> and decoded again to base 10 will get <i>"1234"</i>
<br><br> Encoding "0001" to base 3 will get <i>"1"</i> and decoding again will get <i>"1"</i> instead of <i>"0001"</i> again.<br><br>

----------------
<br><br><br><br>
```

Any help would be very appreciated. Thanks a million in advance!

Comment: `raw: 0001
encoded: 1
decoded: 1` Why is encoded == "1". It is because the algorithm takes the "0" because of the position [0] in the charset as data (integer) == 0. Thats why "encoded" is wrong. `"1" in Base 3 !=  "0001" (as string not as int) in base64 (decimal string)`. I'd like to fix this issue.

Comment: Now it makes sense. So you need to not have the script cast the string to a number.

Comment: Yeah you got it right. The issue occurs in the conversion because it takes the int 0 * x == 0 instead of "0"

Comment: Too bad that it seems like nobody is able to fix my problem. Mhm, thats a pitty.